# Запустить CS-Cart с Bitbucket на удаленный сервер

Tags: git, bitbucket, cs-cart

Дали задание установить *CS-Cart* на локальный комп, затем залить его на *Bitbucket* через *Git*, а потом с *Bitbucket* перенести на сервер и запустить его там. Я все сделал, но при запуске с сервера у меня не открывается магазин, а просто показывает белый экран.

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы магазин заработал?

Comment: Спасибо, что поделились с нами такой интересной историей. Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: что мне надо сделать, чтобы магазин заработал?

Comment: Расскажите подробно, как вы его запускаете локально и как на сервере, а ещё как переносите на сервер. Пока что ничего не ясно.

Comment: локально localhost/cscart. Я создал репозиторий на битбакете, закинул туда файлы этого магазина, а потом клонировал этот репозиторий в папку на сервере. При запуске с сервера появляется просто белый экран, не заходит даже в панель администрации. Причем когда я просто устанавливал с локалки на сервер без битбакета, магазин работал